# stdClass Object bing api

Tags: php

I try to take from bing api related results and write script, who take me with print_r($value) this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [__metadata] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uri] => https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/RelatedSearch?Market='en-US'&Query='car'&$skip=0&$top=1
                    [type] => RelatedSearchResult
                )

            [ID] => 8bbe5043-f85b-41b3-b044-3649628fc5cf
            [Title] => Cars Games
            [BingUrl] => http://www.bing.com/search?q=Cars+Games
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [__metadata] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uri] => https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/RelatedSearch?Market='en-US'&Query='car'&$skip=1&$top=1
                    [type] => RelatedSearchResult
                )

            [ID] => b9df73ab-c410-4480-b172-2719643d1120
            [Title] => Car Pictures
            [BingUrl] => http://www.bing.com/search?q=Car+Pictures
        )

)
```

How i can take [Title] and [BingUrl] from this array ? Thank you.

Comment: doesn't this works `$array[0]->Title` and `$array[0]->BingUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` to access array elements and use `->` to access object members.

In your case, it would be `$arr[$index]->Title` and `$arr[$index]->BingUrl`

Most APIs provide results in JSON format, so you may save yourself some headache by using `json_decode($api_result, 1)` to decode them as an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

If $value is array then you can use this code

```
foreach ($value as $item)
{
     echo $item->Title;
     echo $item->BingUrl
}
```